# Above Threshold and Below Threshold in DataTransfer Modifier?

Tags: modifiers, vertex-colors, vertex-paint

I'm working on DataTransfer Modifier to blend vertex color of 2 colors layer , it worked but i dont understand how Mix Mode : Above Threshold and Below Threshhold worked , i tried to modified Mix Factor from 0 to 1 but nothing changed . What is "threshold" that Mix Mode mentioned ? and How to adjust that parameter ?
Sorry for my bad english .
Thanks alot .

Comment: I'm pretty sure It means "replace destination with source, only where source's value is above /  below threshold", and that with color, the threshold will be defined by luminance, (although it's not documented).  It doesn't really make great  sense, with color, IMO. The operation would almost certainly be simpler to define clearly with Geometry Nodes. Can you describe the effect you want to achieve?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qbwo.jpg
this picture includes 3 versions of cabin with AO vertex color, 1st row is a top view and 2nd is bottom view.
I baked AO for a cabin with two versions :
OFF is a version without  hemisphere
ON is a version with hemisphere
MIX is a version when i uses DataTransfer to blend AO between 2 versions OFF and ON with Mix Mode : Add.
As u can see that a version ON had a dark AO on roof of cabin , i'm not only dont want a dark AO roof but also dont want a low contrast of other parts of cabin , i just want to replace destination AO vertex of a dark roof